# Column Value Null After Order By Clause

Tags: sql, datetime, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I am getting column value if order by clause is not applied for my column [pay_date]. Below are the queries to create table and insert dummy value to setup same scenario as mine

```
CREATE TABLE [payment_customer]
(
 pay_date datetime ,
 customer_name text,
 pay_amt Memo,
 bal_amt Memo
)


CREATE TABLE [report_invoice]
(
inv_no text,
 inv_date datetime ,
 pname text,
 grand_total Memo
)

Insert Into report_invoice Values 
('INV/17-17/0001',#2017-08-08 00:00:00#,'Customer 1',1000)
Insert Into report_invoice Values 
('INV/17-17/0002',#2017-08-27 00:00:00#,'Customer 1',300)
Insert Into report_invoice Values 
('INV/17-17/0003',#2017-08-27 00:00:00#,'Customer 1',2000)
Insert Into report_invoice Values 
('INV/17-17/0004',#2017-08-27 00:00:00#,'Customer 2',500)
Insert Into report_invoice Values 
('INV/17-17/0005',#2017-08-28 00:00:00#,'Customer 1',3000)
Insert Into report_invoice Values 
('INV/17-17/0006',#2017-08-29 00:00:00#,'Customer 3',700)


Insert Into payment_customer  Values 
(#2017-08-27 00:00:00#,'Customer 1',500,1500)
Insert Into payment_customer  Values 
(#2017-08-28 00:00:00#,'Customer 2',200,300)
```

Final Query

```
Select * from
(
Select t1.inv_no,t1.inv_date,t1.pname,t1.grand_total , t2.pay_date,t2.customer_name,t2.pay_amt,t2.bal_amt from report_invoice t1
LEFT  join payment_customer t2 on t1.inv_date = t2.pay_date and t1.pname = t2.customer_name
UNION ALL
Select t2.inv_no,t2.inv_date,t2.pname,t2.grand_total ,  t1.pay_date,t1.customer_name,t1.pay_amt,t1.bal_amt  from payment_customer t1 
LEFT  join report_invoice t2 on  t1.pay_date = t2.inv_date where t2.inv_date is null 
) as v
order by IIF(IsNull(v.inv_date),v.pay_date,v.inv_date)
```

Result I am getting, But As can see customer_name,pay_amt,bal_amt dated 28/08/2017 is repetative
    inv_no          inv_date    pname                   grand_total  pay_date         customer_name                         pay_amt    bal_amt

```
INV/17-18/00001 08/08/2017  Veena Industries Ltd.   238.832 
INV/17-18/00002 27/08/2017  Excel Plants            514.95      27/08/2017        Excel Plants & Equipment Pvt. Ltd.         300    214.95
INV/17-18/00003 29/08/2017  I- Tech                 400 
INV/17-18/00004 28/08/2017  VEENA                   514.95      28/08/2017        VEENA                                      300    214.95
INV/17-18/00005 28/08/2017  VEENA                   600
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDr33.png)

Comment: How do you think that `dated 28/08/2017 is ` duplicate record.just check first and  third column for two records is INV/17-18/00004,514.95 and INV/17-18/00005,600 which is completly different.do you really want to show only one record for every individual date .And if yes .which one do you need to show.?

Comment: Actually there are two different tables and wanted to join only once if condition gets satisfied I will require both rows and record of 28/08/2017,VEENA , 300  , 214 only once if also satisfies condition multiple times

Comment: I didn't understad what you are trying to tell . But,when i join your above tables that you mentioned '[payment_customer]' and '[report_invoice]'.what is the required output that you need to show .show me your output in text format in the above question.

Comment: See my updated question

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify the order of fields and to use true date expressions in Access SQL syntax, and *do* use *Currency* for amounts:

```
pay_date datetime,
customer_name text,
pay_amt Currency,
bal_amt Currency

inv_no text,
inv_date datetime,
pname text,
grand_total Currency

Insert Into report_invoice (inv_no,inv_date,pname,grand_total) 
Values ('INV/17-17/0001',#2017-08-08 00:00:00#,'Customer 1',1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

After some modification try this

```
Select * from
(
Select t1.inv_no,t1.inv_date,t1.pname,t1.grand_total , t2.pay_date,t2.customer_name,t2.pay_amt,t2.bal_amt from report_invoice t1
LEFT  join payment_customer t2 on t1.inv_date = t2.pay_date and cast(t1.pname as varchar(50)) = cast(t2.customer_name as varchar(50))
UNION ALL
Select t2.inv_no,t2.inv_date,t2.pname,t2.grand_total ,  t1.pay_date,t1.customer_name,t1.pay_amt,t1.bal_amt  from payment_customer t1 
LEFT  join report_invoice t2 on  t1.pay_date = t2.inv_date where t2.inv_date is null 
) as v
order by IIF(v.inv_date is null,v.pay_date,v.inv_date)

Output -

inv_no  inv_date    pname   grand_total pay_date    customer_name   pay_amt bal_amt
INV/17-17/0001  2017-08-08 00:00:00.000 Customer 1  1000.00 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
INV/17-17/0002  2017-08-27 00:00:00.000 Customer 1  300.00  2017-08-27 00:00:00.000 Customer 1  500.00  1500.00
INV/17-17/0003  2017-08-27 00:00:00.000 Customer 1  2000.00 2017-08-27 00:00:00.000 Customer 1  500.00  1500.00
INV/17-17/0004  2017-08-27 00:00:00.000 Customer 2  500.00  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
INV/17-17/0005  2017-08-28 00:00:00.000 Customer 1  3000.00 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
INV/17-17/0006  2017-08-29 00:00:00.000 Customer 3  700.00  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

**EDIT**

Check if it is working or not

```
Select v.inv_no,v.inv_date,v.pname,v.grand_total , v.pay_date,v.customer_name,v.pay_amt,v.bal_amt from
(
Select  t1.inv_no,t1.inv_date,t1.pname,t1.grand_total , t2.pay_date,t2.customer_name,t2.pay_amt,t2.bal_amt,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by t2.pay_amt,t2.bal_amt,t1.inv_date order by t1.inv_date) rn  from report_invoice t1
LEFT  join payment_customer t2 on t1.inv_date = t2.pay_date and cast(t1.pname as varchar(50)) = cast(t2.customer_name as varchar(50))
UNION ALL
Select t2.inv_no,t2.inv_date,t2.pname,t2.grand_total ,  t1.pay_date,t1.customer_name,t1.pay_amt,t1.bal_amt,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by t1.pay_amt,t1.bal_amt,t2.inv_date order by t2.inv_date) rn  from payment_customer t1 
LEFT  join report_invoice t2 on  t1.pay_date = t2.inv_date where t2.inv_date is null 
) as v
where rn = 1
order by IIF(v.inv_date is null,v.pay_date,v.inv_date)
```

Output

```
inv_no  inv_date    pname   grand_total pay_date    customer_name   pay_amt bal_amt
INV/17-17/0001  2017-08-08 00:00:00.000 Customer 1  1000.00 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
INV/17-17/0004  2017-08-27 00:00:00.000 Customer 2  500.00  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
INV/17-17/0002  2017-08-27 00:00:00.000 Customer 1  300.00  2017-08-27 00:00:00.000 Customer 1  500.00  1500.00
INV/17-17/0005  2017-08-28 00:00:00.000 Customer 1  3000.00 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
INV/17-17/0006  2017-08-29 00:00:00.000 Customer 3  700.00  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: As you can see 2017-08-27 00:00:00.000 Customer 1  500.00  1500.00
 is coming twice I want that to appear once only

Comment: Error missing operator in query expression RowNumber()

Comment: But it is working fine here. Are you trying in sqlserver?

Comment: Clearly mentioned its MS Access

Comment: *Clearly mentioned its MS Access* - by adding the sql-server tag. Right.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct this is what you need.

```
Select distinct inv_no,inv_date,pname.grand_total,pay_date,customer_name,pay_amt,bal_amt from
(
Select t1.inv_no as inv_no,t1.inv_date as inv_date,t1.pname as pname,t1.grand_total as grand_total , 
t2.pay_date as pay_date,t2.customer_name as customer_name,t2.pay_amt as pay_amt,t2.bal_amt as bal_amt from report_invoice t1
LEFT  join payment_customer t2 on t1.inv_date = t2.pay_date and t1.pname = t2.customer_name
UNION ALL
Select t2.inv_no,t2.inv_date,t2.pname,t2.grand_total ,  t1.pay_date,t1.customer_name,t1.pay_amt,t1.bal_amt  from payment_customer t1 
LEFT  join report_invoice t2 on  t1.pay_date = t2.inv_date where t2.inv_date is null 
) as v
order by IIF(v.inv_date is null,v.pay_date,v.inv_date)
```

**Note:** Isnull will expect two arguments to pass into it .

**CASE is portable across all SQL platforms whereas IIF is SQL SERVER 2012+ specific** .

Comment: Error Missing Operator case when v.inv_date is null then v.pay_date else v.inv_date end asc in MS Access

Comment: @RahulDesai now i've updated the query.once check with it

Comment: Same Error Error Missing Operator case when v.inv_date is null then v.pay_date else v.inv_date end asc in MS Access

Comment: I thought you where SQL Server.CASE is not available in MS Access, look at Switch, IIF .I've update your query with IIF .check the query now -:)

Comment: It works but results (#2017-08-27 00:00:00#,'Customer 1',500,1500) data twice after join I want it to appear only once

Comment: @RahulDesai Use UNION operator instead of UNION ALL in your query then there will be no duplicates.you will get distinct data .

Comment: using Union also it results twice

Comment: See my updated question In which I have attached image of my result with the query

Comment: @RahulDesai im sorry the above link for image has been blocked by admin in my machine for security reasons.let me change the query as per my guess it might help you.

Comment: check the query now.I've made changes to it.

Comment: missing operator in expression distinct inv_no

Comment: @RahulDesai there is a type mistake in the query for 'Distinct' .you should atleast look into the query and have to make the changes for typo mistakes.this is not a school to serve you all the free code .anyway.i've changed it again (:-

Comment: Agreed with your point but Distinct in our case will not work at all

Comment: Atleast try to make me to see your sample data as text format in your question.so,that i can help you.